# XSD 1.1 validation failure upon using xerces with JBOSS EAP 7.1

Tags: java, xerces, jboss-eap-7, xsd-1.1

My web application is deployed in JBOSS EAP 7.1 server and uses jdk 1.8. I needed to validate my XML against XSD 1.1 using following xerces dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.opengis.cite.xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl-xsd11</artifactId>
        <version>2.12-beta-r1667115</version>
</dependency>
```

My code for validation was working fine when run standalone. However, the same code is failing at following line when I am deploying my web application on JBOSS server.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
```

I am getting following error:

```
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory cannot be created
```

How can I use xerces to validate my XSD 1.1 version inside JBOSS EAP 7.1?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)), that takes the class name of the factory. The class of the factory is 'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchema11Factory', you shall also need the 'xercesImpl-xsd11-2.12-beta-r1667115.jar' on classpath.

Comment: I did `SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance ("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1", "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchema11Factory",null)` and added `xercesImpl-xsd11-2.12-beta-r1667115.jar` on classpath. However, it is still not working for me. I am still getting `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: W3C_XML_SCHEMA11_NS_URI`

Comment: You should not be getting this error, it usually will happen if there is another xercesimpl.jar shadowing the above mentioned jar. Refer: https://github.com/opengeospatial/ets-kml2/issues/6 the class is org.xerces.impl.Constants. I checked in the above jar, the file has the field defined. Check for jar shadowing i.e. if your app server classpath has one version and web app the other. You are using JBOSS so not completely sure but in Tomcat it becomes a problem with classloading; perhaps both load classes the same way without referring to parent class loader, check once.

Comment: My WEB-INF/lib had two xerces with different version. I excluded unwanted version from getting packaged. So my error stopped coming in newInstance(). However, now I am getting error as `org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/cta-full-xpath-checking' is not recognized` at `factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/cta-full-xpath-checking",true)`

Comment: Don't set the feature, it is not necessary for schema 1.1 validation, refer: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html

Comment: I added xerces2-j(with xsd 1.1) jars at local maven repo. However, while deploying in my jboss, xml validation is still taking some different. I had excluded xerces present in jboss modules as well. Yet, it did not work for me inside container.

Comment: What difficulty are you facing now?